# Angular factory function always returns null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying store the currentUser object in a factory so it can be accessed throughout my app. However, whenever I call CurrentUserFactory.GetCurrentUser() it returns null. I've verified that everything is fine server side and it's receiving the user object. But it always returns null.

```
angular.module('myWebApp.services')
    .factory('CurrentUserFactory', ['SettingsFactory', '$http', function(SettingsFactory, $http) {
            var CurrentUserFactory = {};
            var currentUser = null;

            CurrentUserFactory.GetCurrentUser = function() {
                if (!currentUser) {
                    $http.get(SettingsFactory.myAPIUrl + 'api/users/current', { withCredentials: true }).then(function (response) {
                        currentUser = response.data;
                    });
                }
                return currentUser;
            }

            return CurrentUserFactory;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: It's an AJAX call  - you can't return from it - you need to use promises or callbacks.

Comment: You can initialize your `currentUser` with object and then copy all response fields to that object. Then you will get eventually filled user.

Comment: @tymeJV Is `.then` not a promise?

Comment: `$http.get` is a promise, but you didn't return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asynchronous call to `$http` returns a promise, but the function itself returns `currentUser`, which is `null`. You need to return the `$http` promise, if `currentUser` is `null`, or return `currentUser` wrapped in a promise, if it's not `null`:

```
angular.module('myWebApp.services')
    .factory('CurrentUserFactory', ['SettingsFactory', '$http', '$q', function(SettingsFactory, $http, $q) {
            var CurrentUserFactory = {};
            var currentUser = null;

            CurrentUserFactory.GetCurrentUser = function() {
                if (!currentUser) {
                    return $http.get(SettingsFactory.myAPIUrl + 'api/users/current', { withCredentials: true }).then(function (response) {
                        currentUser = response.data;
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }
                return $q.resolve(currentUser);
            }

            return CurrentUserFactory;
        }
    ]);
```

**Usage:**

Because the function returns a promise, you need a [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) block to get the results:

```
CurrentUserFactory.GetCurrentUser().then(function(currentUser) {
    console.log(currentUser);
});
```

Comment: Or `return Promise.resolve(currentUser)` instead of `$q` dependency

Comment: It's angular $q is part of the framework, and it also invoke apply, which angular 2 way binding depends on.

Comment: I find promises ugly. Is it possible to do this in a way that `GetCurrentUser` can be used like this: `var cu = CurrentUserFactory.GetCurrentUser();`?

Comment: You can do that using [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). However, since their not supported natively by IE, you'll need to transpile the code using babel.

Comment: @Legion, you can. With synchronous ajax. Try it and may be you find promises not so ugly. :)

Comment: Is it possible to do it synchronously instead? I can't have anything proceed until it's resolved.

Comment: @Legion, you can. With synchronous ajax. Try it and may be you find promises not so ugly. :)

Comment: All ajax calls are asynchronous, so you can't. Embrace promises, angular is based on them.

Comment: @Legion -- Finding code "ugly" is a pretty bad reason not to use it IMO - synchronous requests give a shit experience to the end user.

Comment: @tymeJV I prefer to load everything up front if the load time is short. In this case my load time is under 2 seconds and then I don't have to talk to the server again until the user saves their data. I also don't have to deal with situations where only some of the data is loaded.

Comment: @Legion - are you using a router? You can use resolve in the route, and get the data synchronously in the controller.

Comment: @OriDrori I'm using `ui-router`. If you're going to suggest a resolve, yeah, I just came to the same conclusion and put the fetch in my root state's resolve.

Comment: @Legion - indeed. That would give you the data synchronously, but you'll still have to return a promise.

Comment: @OriDrori In the resolve, yes. But when I call `GetCurrentUser` I don't have to use `.then`.

Comment: "Under 2 seconds" - time is irrelevant, you can still load everything up front asynchronously and give a much better experience. The UI can load in milliseconds while your data calls finish in the background. The overall point I'm really trying to drive home is that synchronous requests should be avoided at all costs!

Comment: @tymeJV We'll have to remain in disagreement on the issue as the comments aren't suited to this kind of discussion.